# NoReverseMatch with Regex when Trying To create Email from Template that takes an url as the parameter

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to send email from Django using gmail to gmail. with a `send_mail`:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class AuthenticationView(View):

    @classmethod
    def send_email(cls, request, user):
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        mail_subject = 'Activate your Poros account.'
        message = render_to_string('email_verification.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = user.email
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()
```

Then I set url patterns for my app like this below:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path

from .views.activation import activate

from .views import UserView, ProfileView, AuthenticationView

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('auth/', AuthenticationView.as_view()),
    path('profiles/<str:pk>/', ProfileView.as_view()),
    url(r'activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        activate, name='activate'),
]
```

and will included by the project urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'),)
]
```

and the `activate` view is coming from an `activate()` like this below:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth import login

from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode
from accounts.utilities import account_activation_token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

The error come when I tried to get url from url name `activate` in the The `email_verification` template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    Hi {{ user.username }},
    Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
    http://{{ domain }}/accounts{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

and this problem returns me error when the `send_mail` called. It gives me this:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/users/ Reverse for 'activate' with keyword
arguments '{'uidb64': b'ZDRkMTBkODBiNzc3NDFlZWE4NzczMjRmNTM1MDg3M2M',
'token': '4tq-2981c84990bfedab3525'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['accounts\\/activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

The url I use in the template seems like doesn't match with my url patterns. Is there any way to use a normal path for this to prevent super-confusing-regex matching? Or anyone has better approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with your regex, it is that you are passing a bytestring into the template instead of a normal string. You need to call `decode()` on your uid:

```
'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
```